# Datatables Ajax call not displaying data

Tags: ajax, datatables-1.10

I'm using the datatables library to display some data and would like to update this every 30 seconds with data fetched form a URL. I've followed the api documentation and have implemented the code below to do this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   var table = $('#performance_summary').DataTable( {
        ajax: 'https://myjasonurl.com'
    } );

    setInterval( function () {
        table.ajax.reload();
    }, 30000 );
        });
```

When the page loads I can see that the correct URL is called to retrieve data, and data is returned in the correct format to display properly in the table (I've checked this works by loading this into the table directly). Unfortunately the resulting datatable when using the ajax call states that it is "loading" but never loads/shows the data, does anyone have any idea of how I fix this?

Comment: you are calling the ajax url before the previous call completes, you can use jquery promise

Comment: have removed the second call, apparently I dont need to do this. Still no luck though, the data is being loaded but isn't being passed into the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `DataTable().ajax.url` function, 
Following code works fine for me:

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    var table = $('#performance_summary').DataTable({
        paging: false,
        searching: false,
        ajax: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/897v1",
        columns: [{
            "title":"Test",
            "data": "test"
        }]
    });
    setInterval( function () {
        $('#performance_summary').DataTable().ajax.url(
              "https://api.myjson.com/bins/897v1"
           ).load();
    }, 3000 );
});
```

here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ju2bmtm7/84/